# Посмотреть иерархию классов в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Как в VS можно в удобном виде посмотреть иерархию(Что от какого класса досталось и т п) в удобном виде?

Сейчас в обозреватели объектов я вижу методы, но по их приходится просчелкивать, что бы увидеть откуда он пришел.

Может быть есть более удобная штука?

Comment: Code map уже пробовали? https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/mt238403.aspx

Answer (score 2):

В редакторе кода нажимаете правой кнопкой на метод и выбираете "View Call Hierarchy".

Ну или последовательно Ctrl+K, Ctrl+T

Comment: Ну или последовательно Ctrl+K, Ctrl+T